# jQuery broken in IE7 & IE9 only

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-7

For some reason, on this really simple page, jQuery will not work on IE7 or IE9, yet it works in IE8 and all other modern browsers. Any ideas why this might be the case?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".thumb").fancybox();

$("a.group").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false
});

$('.note').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.result').next('.notes').slideToggle();
});

});
```

Baffling. Any help would be greatly appreciated! BTW, if you'd like to check out the whole deal, you can see it at http://moveout.dancormier.com
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have IE, so can you tell use what's wrong? How's it broken? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I just tried this in IE7 and it seemed to be working? Certainly the toggling of notes was working like a champ and even the fancybox calls worked. What specifically is broken?

Comment: The javascript was broken entirely.
@SteveWellens suggestion fixed it.
Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a newer, or older, version of jQuery.

Comment: Surprisingly, this seems to have been the issue. Somewhere along the line, the IE7 problem went away, but the IE9 issue persisted. When I changed the jquery from 1.5.0 to 1.5.2, the IE9 issue went away.
BTW: To those of you asking, the javascript as a whole was broken. Nothing worked. But this seemed to fix it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us what errors you're encountering when viewed in IE? (The prospect of booting up a Windows VM and IE to look for myself is not exactly appealing)

**A guess:**

A lot of times IE7/IE8 seems to be very picky about JSON notation. e.g., if you end an object literal with a `,` it bugs out.

```
{foo1: 'bar',
 foo2: 'baz',} // <-- This , seems to be ignored by everything but IE
```

So perhaps you should play around with your object literal there? Maybe don't quote the keys and remove the superfluous spacing between the key, `:` and value.

**General advice:**

Try using the [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/) to debug problems in IE. It's certainly no FireBug but its the best you can get for free for IE debugging.

Comment: IE is fine with quoted object keys

Comment: I've run into the 'trailing comma' issue before. It took me a while to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are the errors that you're getting?

I don't know about jQuery and IE *per se*, but I did have to tango with fancybox a while back with IE 7. I kept getting UI layout errors related to the `IFRAME`s that fancybox were throwing out.

If this sounds like what you're getting, [I posted a blog post on a workaround I did at that time](http://richardneililagan.com/2009/12/problems-with-fancybox-1-2-6-in-internet-explorer-7/) if you're interested in looking at it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @richardneililagan. Fancybox wasn't the issue this time. Updating jquery from 1.5.0 to 1.5.2 fixed it.